# How to skip checkstyle and modernizer in maven

Tags: maven

I do have a multi directories source code in java and want to compile just part of it. It has worked, until I included a new code and tried to compile skiping checkstyle and modernizer, using:

mvn  clean install -Dcheckstyle.skip=true -Dmodernizer.skip=true

BTW, i have tried to disable it from pom.xml to no avail. It does not work either.

It SIMPLY does not work and both plugins are still executed. Does any have a clue on what may be happening?